# Is a way to reset nuget timeout in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

My network is limit by some security agreements of my company so that access to external sites will be very slow. So when I install some large nuget package, I  alawys get the time out error:

> has timed out after 100000ms.

So I want to set nuget timeout so that I can retry with my will?

I have no idea how to set the timeout so i will appreciate if anyone can help me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is a way to reset nuget timeout in Visual Studio?

The timeout is the default timeout of nuget client, . I don't believe there is a way to increase the timeout.

As workaround, you can try to use the VPN or set your own NuGet repository locally should be a great recommendation:

Steps to set local fed:

1. Create a local folder, such as, "D:\LocalServer"
2. Add this path to the package source, Tools->Options->NuGet Package Manager->Package Sources.

   [image]
3. Download the package Microsoft.Net.Native.SharedLibrary from nuget.org, then you can install the package to your project from the local feed.

Comment: OK, I will use the local feed. Thanks.

Comment: Brilliant. The same works for Visual Studio for Mac, and after downloading every single dependency (a one time operation), opening a solution is so much faster

Comment: This was the only information I could find anywhere on the net that would solve this problem which I was also having.